# Clone multiple fields value not wroking properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried this below.

```js
$('#btn3').click(function() {
  $('.test3').val($('.bbb').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn3">Copy Each hidden value to text value</button><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="15"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="40"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="60"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="100"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="110"><br>
```

I would to works each field with exact value. value should be 10,40,100 when click the 'Copy Each hidden value to text value' button.

Comment: And what issue you are facing with that code ?

Comment: After click, all value returns as 10.

Comment: Given the button states you want to copy the hidden inputs to the visible ones, should the values not then be `10`, `40` and `100`? It's not clear from your code exactly what you're trying to do, although to do what you need you'll need a loop

Comment: For copying values one to one controls you need to use loop. And you will have to assign id to each of them and use them in loop.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/ and https://api.jquery.com/prev/ should help you.

Comment: Why would you need all these hidden fields with same values as the visible ones? Seems like a very strange configuration, especially since none of them have `name`

Comment: @Jeny no problem, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#btn3').click(function(){
   $('.test3').each(function(key){
    $(this).val($(".bbb").get(key).value);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn3">Copy Each hidden value to text value</button><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="15"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="40"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="60"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="100"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="110"><br>
```

Comment: OMG, Special Thanks for you.

Comment: According my thanks comment is the top thanks for you ATM :) I need more reputation to hit thanks :( Anyway, please will hit you as useful.

Comment: You don't need to vote only **checked** confirm for help others .

Comment: Welcome dear sir.

Comment: Hi Farhad Bagherlo, Would you review this code again? The code is not working when i am implement at submit form. Means, the value changes working perfectly but when click the save button and after reload the value is returns as default.

Comment: Add the name of the hidden input  and get those names in your code behind function .

Comment: If you could not fix it. Email me your code to check it out.  Bagherlo@live.com

Comment: Still not working, i think this is not deploy on changes Fields,

Answer (score 2):

The results you’re getting are expected for the code you’ve posted.  If you want each `test3` to be assigned the previous elements value (`bbb`), use the `.prev()` function in a loop of the elements.

```
$('#btn3').click(function(){
  $('.test3').each(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).prev('.bbb').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: @Jeny I don’t see any difference.  This code will do what you want.

Comment: Output value should be 10,40,100 when click the 'Copy Each hidden value to text value' button.

Comment: According your code, its output fields become empty.

Comment: Note that `prev()` won't work here as the related inputs do not follow each other.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can pass a function to `val()` which retrieves the value from the `.bbb` closest to the given `.test3` element:

```js
$('#btn3').click(function() {
  $('.test3').val(function() {
    return $(this).prevAll('.bbb:first').val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn3">Copy Each hidden value to text value</button><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="15"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="40"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="60"><br>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" value="100"><br>
<input type="text" class="test3" value="110"><br>
```

Note that you need to use `prevAll()` here as the `.bbb` and `.test3` elements are not siblings due to the `<br />` between them.

Comment: Hi dear thanks for your job, As i can see your code is working here with br or without br (not conflict) but cant understand why its not working with our site.my site has table with td and no br tag inside the input. My site with return empty :(

Comment: Probably because the HTML you put in the question wasn't the same as what's actually used in your site.

Comment: Not exactly, but your code is ok. Maybe some reasons to get conflict.